# How to add a custom title bar with an image as background in android studio

Tags: android

I have found several answers on here as to how to change the background color and add a custom icon to the title bar in android studio but am having difficulties finding an answer for how to use a custom image as the background instead of just a color in the title bar. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

sadly you cannot add images as the background on both the header and textView/webView that's why you don't see any apps on android with image backgrounds. you could try using html instead of xml, like:

> replace colors.xml, styles.xml, ect with colors.html, styles.html, ect

but i doubt that will work. hopefully they will add this feature later in the android sdk.